# NERDTree and buffer handling

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I've setup an "IDE" based on VIM and NERDTree for programming using FreePascal. Overall, it's working great, but I can't find how to tell NERDTree to change it's default behavior regarding VIM buffers.

Currently, every time I open a file in NERDTree, it creates a new buffer. If the file is already open in another buffer, it could be nice to have a shortcut to just go to the former buffer, instead of creating a new one for the same file. This could be specially usefull for programmers who must go back and forth between files.

Any hint?

Comment: Could you please specify your settings/setup/versions?
I'm on the most recent Vim & NERDTree, but can't reproduce the problem.

E.g. open a file with 'o' from NERDTree, then open another, then reopen the first (from NERDTree), but after checking :buffers, there is only one for it.

Comment: Well, yes, the buffer number is not affected. As you noted, It doesn't add a new buffer, but the effect is different if you press "o", than when you type :b<number>. I should reformulate my question, what I want is the same result I get when I type :b<number>. A simple test is just open a file, then position the cursor in some line, open another file, then go back to the first file. If you open it using NERDTree, the cursor is on position 0, on the other hand, if you type :b1, the cursor is on the right place.

My NERDTree version is 4.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just had to read through my .vimrc (actually _vimrc :-( ) to see why it works for me.

According to the superb but slightly outdated [Vim faq](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html#5.5), an autocommand helps me:

```
 au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
                     \ exe "normal g'\"" | endif
```